# Error while deploying the app "reading document at index 1: yaml: unmarshal errors: key "chart" already set in map"

Tags: kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, helmfile

When deploying the application in the Kubernetes cluster (AWS EKS v1.26) and with the updated client as `kubectl@1.26.3`, `helm@3.11.3`, and `helmfile@0.153.1`, I'm getting the below issue

```
failed to read install.yaml: reading document at index 1: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 195: key "chart" already set in map
  line 202: key "chart" already set in map
  line 209: key "chart" already set in map
  line 216: key "chart" already set in map
  line 223: key "chart" already set in map
  line 230: key "chart" already set in map
  line 237: key "chart" already set in map
  line 244: key "chart" already set in map
  line 251: key "chart" already set in map
  line 258: key "chart" already set in map
  line 265: key "chart" already set in map
  line 272: key "chart" already set in map
  line 279: key "chart" already set in map
  line 286: key "chart" already set in map
  line 293: key "chart" already set in map
  line 307: key "chart" already set in map
  line 326: key "chart" already set in map
  line 333: key "chart" already set in map
  line 340: key "chart" already set in map
  line 347: key "chart" already set in map
  line 354: key "chart" already set in map
```

Here `install.yaml` (configuration) will have a lot of charts to be deployed so, the `chart` have multiple copies but in different anchors.

Everything works fine if we're using `helmfile@1.46.0`

Comment: I can hand-wave at some changes in Helmfile 0.150.0 that have caused some problems for me, but the error message on its own isn't really enough to tell what might be going wrong.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?